# Tabs not working if I put additional divs

Tags: jquery, tabs

I need to implement jQuery tab plugin. I have tried implementing this http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-jquery-folder-tabs

I don't know why it is not working if I put additional divs in the first tab. If I put this in the first it is not visible. I want to put the above HTML in the below div tag with name tab1. I tried but it didn't work.

```
<div class="oncloseTemp">
    <div class="oncloseLeft">
        <div style="border:1px solid black; height:230px; width:48%; float:left;">
        <div class="leftOne-1">
            <img class="imageLeft-1" src="Picture1.png" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%;" />
        </div>
        <div class="priceTag-1">EK007 | Rs 550000 | 18K</div>
            <div class="checkCart" style="border:none;">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <img class="cart" src="Picture2.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="oncloseRight" >
        <div class="rightOne">
            <img class="imageRight" src="13.jpg" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%;"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eAT3z/ here is my fiddle.

Comment: Can you please share some more code which explain better ?

Comment: i used plugin , it is wrking with something like text, but if i put div its not wrking.

Comment: Its hide content because you $("#content div").hide();  this on document load. You post that content in div so when page load its check content div and hide it.

Comment: @anuRadha Have checked my fiddle ?

Comment: @anuRadha.. check out this: http://jsfiddle.net/eAT3z/5/